# Reading from serial port fails

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have the following C program:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not open device");
    }
    printf("Device opened\n");

    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(fd, &options);
    cfmakeraw(&options);
    cfsetispeed(&options, B19200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B19200);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

    char txpacket[] = {0x23, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0xdd, 0xf9};
    ssize_t written = write(fd, txpacket, sizeof(txpacket));
    printf("Written %d bytes\n", written);

    printf("Starting to wait for target to respond\n");
    while(1)
    {
        fd_set readset;
        FD_ZERO(&readset);
        FD_SET(fd, &readset);
        int nCount = select(fd + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(nCount > 0)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(fd, &readset))
            {
                int i;
                char buffer[128];
                ssize_t bytesread = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                printf("Received %d bytes\n", bytesread);
                for(i = 0; i < bytesread; i++)
                {
                    printf("  %02x", buffer[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program opens the serial device /dev/ttyS0, writes a sequence of data to it and starts listening for a response. I get the following output:

```
Device opened
Written 6 bytes
Starting to wait for target to respond
Received 0 bytes
Received 0 bytes
Received 0 bytes
Received 0 bytes
Received 0 bytes
Received 0 bytes
...
```

And the application consumes 100% CPU. I'm not able to receive any data, even though the target hardware actually transmits it.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`read()` returning 0 indicates the end-of-file condition.  You should check for that and break out of the loop if it occurs.

As to what's causing that - end-of-file on a serial port indicates it has detected a hangup, meaning that the DCD line has been dropped.

You can set the `CLOCAL` flag in `options.c_cflag` to ignore the modem control lines, if your device doesn't set them properly.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed what was causing the problem.

Comment: Damn, did not see the CLOCAL thing !

Comment: Had the same problem, thanks for the tip.  Didn't realize cfmakeraw dind't see those two obvious flags.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been fighting my cellular modem the whole day.

Comment: Old thread here I know but i'm facing this issue now myself - what is the recommended course of action if read() is returning 0? Do you need to flush and close the port and re-open it? Thanks.

Comment: @Fra: To reset the hangup condition on a serial port you need to close and reopen it.

Comment: @caf: Ok makes sense. Now if the serial port is in an fd[] set being monitored by select() statement, do I have to remove it from the set or can I simply just close/re-open in place?

Comment: @Fra: If you close and reopen there's no guarantee that you will get the same file descriptor number back, in which case you'll have to remove the old number and add the new one - so you might as well just remove and readd regardless.

Comment: @caf: Thanks for the help here. I will try and implement that. Is it as simple as: close(fd[x]); THEN fd[x] = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY ); Or is there other steps required?

Comment: @Fra: You may also need to use `tcgetattr()` / `tcsetattr()` on the newly opened file descriptor to ensure the terminal settings are what you need.  And as noted earlier, if `fd[x]` has changed then you'll need to remove the old one from any `fd_set` or similar.

Comment: @caf: Makes sense. When you say "if fd[x] has changed" - can I simply just replace the variable at that memory location with the newly opened path? I don't totally understand what you mean by "has changed". Thank!

Comment: @Fra: The new file descriptor returned by `open()` is not necessarily going to be the same number as the one you just closed, so if the old file descriptor was recorded somewhere else (like in an `fd_set`), you'll need to remove it and replace it with the newly opened one.

Answer (score 1):

You should try without the O_NONBLOCK flag. in raw mode, if the settings of `c_cc[VMIN]` and `c_cc[VTIME]` is 0, the serial port behave like this (according to man cfmakeraw) :

> If data is available, read returns
>   immediately, with the lesser of the
>   number of bytes available, or the
>   number of bytes requested. If no data
>   is available, read returns 0

So what you should try is :

```
options->c_cc[VMIN]=1;
```